# If three out of ten columns are not returning null in sql server, should return specific value in another column

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns

I have 10 columns named from p1,p2,p3,...,p10.
If any two columns have value rather than NULL, I need a column named Fee which should return 1200.
If three and more columns have value rather than NULL, I need that column named Fee should return 1800.

```
p1      p2      p3      p4      p5      p6      p7      p8      p9      p10      Fee
NULL    ENG     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    POL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    ENG     NULL    ECO     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    ENG     TEL     ECO     HIS     POL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    ECO     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Should be like this..

```
p1      p2      p3      p4      p5      p6      p7      p8      p9      p10      Fee
NULL    ENG     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1200
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    POL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1200
NULL    ENG     NULL    ECO     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1200
NULL    ENG     TEL     ECO     HIS     POL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1800
NULL    NULL    NULL    ECO     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1200
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd suggest a `CASE` expression and some addition.

Comment: how should i take each column name while using ```CASE```?

Comment: hint: `CASE WHEN p1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ...` :) Have a go, and if you fail then please do post your attempt(s).

Comment: Your expected result doesn't match your description of your business rule. You're showing all rows at 1200 except the one with 3+ matches. Which is correct?

Comment: I've asked to return 1200 if 2 or less columns are not null and 1800 if 3 and more columns..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Example**

```
Update YourTable 
   set Fee = case when len(concat(left(p1,1),left(p2,1),left(p3,1),left(p4,1),left(p5,1),left(p6,1),left(p7,1),left(p8,1),left(p9,1),left(p10,1))) <=3 then 1200 else 1800 end
```

**Update Table**

[image]

> **EDIT - If values are always 3 characters**

```
Update YourTable 
   set Fee = case when len(concat(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10))/3 <=3 then 1200 else 1800 end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    p1 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    p2 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    p3 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    p4 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    p5 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    p6 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    p7 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    p8 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    p9 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    p10 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    Fee VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO @tbl(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, Fee) VALUES( NULL,    'ENG',     NULL,    NULL,    NULL ,   NULL,    NULL ,   NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, Fee) VALUES( NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    'POL',     NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, Fee) VALUES( NULL,    'ENG',     NULL,    'ECO',     NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, Fee) VALUES( NULL,    'ENG',     'TEL',    'ECO',     'HIS',     'POL',     NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, Fee) VALUES( NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    'ECO',     NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL)

SELECT p1, p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10, a.NoOfColumnWithoutNull,
Fee = CASE WHEN a.NoOfColumnWithoutNull = 2 THEN 1200
      WHEN a.NoOfColumnWithoutNull = 3 THEN 1800
      ELSE 0 END
  FROM (
SELECT p1, p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10, 
NoOfColumnWithoutNull = 
IIF(LEN(p1) > 0,1,0) + IIF(LEN(p2) > 0,1,0) + IIF(LEN(p3) > 0,1,0) + IIF(LEN(p4) > 0,1,0) + IIF(LEN(p5) > 0,1,0) + IIF(LEN(p6) > 0,1,0) 
+ IIF(LEN(p7) > 0,1,0) + IIF(LEN(p8) > 0,1,0) + IIF(LEN(p9) > 0,1,0) + IIF(LEN(p10) > 0,1,0) 
FROM @tbl ) AS a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (p1 char(3),p2 char(3),p3 char(3),p4 char(3),p5 char(3),p6 char(3)
,Fee AS CASE WHEN CASE WHEN p1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                 +CASE WHEN p2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                 +CASE WHEN p3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                 +CASE WHEN p4 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                 +CASE WHEN p5 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                 +CASE WHEN p6 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END > 3 THEN 1800 ELSE 1200 END
)
insert into @t values (NULL,'ENG',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
insert into @t values (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'POL',NULL)
insert into @t values (NULL,'ENG',NULL,'ECO',NULL,NULL)
insert into @t values (NULL,'ENG','TEL','ECO','HIS','POL')
insert into @t values (NULL,NULL,NULL,'ECO',NULL,NULL)

select * from @t
```